# concurrent logins from same browser's multiple window

Tags: php, session, cookies

In my `PHP` application I want to prevent concurrent logins of same user from one browser's multiple window.

Session remains same for browser's multiple window.

E.g. Suppose using Firefox user did login. In same system he open another window of Firefox(not tab), and put application URL then he remains logged in and directly goes to welcome page instead of login page. I want to prevent this.

How can I do it? I could not find proper solution yet.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's rather broad. You don't want to allow the users to log in from multiple different computers?

Comment: @Darren multiple windows of same browser

Comment: @Darren I am done with preventing concurrent logins from multiple computers, multiple browsers. Issue am facing in browser's multiple window. E.g. Firefox's 2 windows in same system

Comment: Sorry, but this is not possible. Only private browsing is separated from the rest.

Comment: @Jack why? there should be some way.

Comment: And why would there be? It's the same browser, so cookies are shared.

Comment: @Shri: why do you think there is a way? Do you know how HTTP and browsers work?

Comment: And, uhm, why do you want to prevent that? What is the point?

Comment: @zerkms because it is demanded. And I knwo sir how http and browsers work but i feel that using js and php we can do it. i'll try.

Comment: @Shri: sometimes when demands are stupid it's your job as a professional to tell they are stupid. When you come to dentist - you follow their advices not learn them doing their job well. The same should happen in programming as well.

Comment: @zerkms Yes. But before that we can try first. it will teach us something different.

Comment: @Shri: it makes no sense to waste time to even try to implement stupid requirements. I'm off. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Windows or tabs are completely irrelevant to a browser, it maintains the same state across all. You're not logging in in a window, you're logging in with a browser, which stores cookies, and sends those cookies back to the server, **regardless of what window or tab it's in**. This is a brain dead requirement without sense or sensibility. Why would anyone care about that in the first place? What bad could possibly happen?

Comment: Non technical person don't know this things. I am also just checking for any possibilities. 'Brain dead requirement without sense or sensibility' don't you think your words are heavy. one can't be aware about all things.

Comment: Requirements don't become more sensible by unawareness. Sorry, the person who created those requirements obviously didn't know what he was talking about, there's no nice way to say that. It's *your* job to find nice words to communicate this to your client/boss/whomever; I'm just stating facts. :o)